# EDA based SOA and NServiceBus: Why not just use SSIS packages?

Tags: ssis, nservicebus

I have been investigating NServiceBus.  I liked the idea of the pub-sub model, and that the only real coupling of the publisher and subscriber is the semantic of the message.  Right now we use SQL replication to sync our data between the databases of different functional areas of our software.  I hate this because our private schema is directly coupled to by the subscriber, and it makes it difficult to change on our side.  I was thinking it would be great to replace this with NServiceBus publications, but the change seems a little drastic.  What about just using something like SSIS?  Can I accomplish the same decoupling using SSIS instead of NServiceBus?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SSIS is based on meta-data and therefore will still need to understand the inner schema of all your data sources and sinks.  If the underlying meta-data for each source/sink changes your packages will have to change.  You also are connecting via MS technologies and are thusly platform coupled.  Since you are moving whole sets of data around it sounds like you may not be temporally coupled(system A has to wait for something to respond in system B).  It's hard to tell without knowing more about the systems.  Lastly SSIS must be aware of the physical locations of all the players in the exchange so you are spatially coupled as well.

In my opinion I don't think you can get to the same place as NSB without developing a lot of the NSB concepts into the packages.  This would require using XML messages over the Sql Broker or something to that effect which has already been solved in NSB(see the NSB Contrib project on Github for the Sql Broker transport).